# cURL ftp transfer scenario

Tags: matlab, curl, ftp, transfer

I'm trying to automate uploading and downloading from an ftp site using cURL inside MAtlab, but I'm having difficulties.  Essentially I want one computer continuously uploading new files to an ftp, yet since there is a disk quota on the ftp, I want another computer continuously downloading and removing those same files from the ftp.

Easy enough, but my problem arises from wanting to make sure that I don't download a file that is still being uploaded, thereby resulting in an incomplete file.

First off, is there a way in cURL to make it so that the file wouldn't be available for download from the ftp site until the entire file has been uploaded?

One way around this is that I could upload files to one directory, and once they are finished uploading, then I could transfer them to a "Finished" directory on the ftp site.  Then the download program would only look for files inside that "Finished" directory.  However, I don't know how to transfer files within an ftp site using cURL.

Is it possible to transfer files between directories on an ftp site using cURL without having to download the file first?

And if anyone else has better ideas on how to perform this task, I'd love to hear em!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload the files using a special name and then rename it when done, and have the download client only download files with that special "upload completed" name style.

Or you move them between directories just as you say (which is essentially a rename as well, just changing the directory too).

With the command line curl, you can perform "raw" commands after the upload with the -Q option and you can even find a tiny example in the curl FAQ: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#Can_I_use_curl_to_delete_rename